# Commands not executing on keybind, but are executing from command pallet

Tags: atom-editor

Got an issue with keymapping commands:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d5nrEO_t7Wo

As you can see in the video, when I call the commands by keyboard shortcut:

- On the first attempt - the function isn't called.
- On the second attempt - the function is called.

Where as, when I call the commands via the command pallet, the commands are called even on the first attempt. Not shown in the video, I can call the commands from the command pallet more than once without fail.

This leeds me to believe there is something wrong with my keymap.coffee:

```
'.editor:not(.mini)':
  'shift-cmd-h': 'hex:view'
  'alt-down':'editor:add-selection-below'
  'alt-up':'editor:add-selection-above'
'.editor':
  'cmd-k':'jxa:compile'
  'shift-cmd-k':'jxa:compileApp'
  'cmd-u':'jxa:execute'
```

However I can see nothing clearly wrong here... So perhaps there's something wrong with my init.js?

https://github.com/sancarn/JXA-Compile/blob/master/src/init.js

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

This was solved by DamnedScholar [here](https://discuss.atom.io/t/commands-not-executing-on-keybind-but-are-executing-from-command-pallet/38506/4).

> Okay, no. It's because cmd-k is bound to **so many things**. Go into Settings -> Keybindings and search for it and you'll see a lot of different things attached to it that are all bindings with multiple key presses. So when you press cmd-k, **Atom waits to see what your next key press will be.** You should consider using something different for jxa:compile.